# How to change firefox javascript engine rules? Error handling

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, error-handling, gecko

```
function hasLiedAboutBrowser()
{
  // Assume browser is Firefox but user agent fakes Google Chrome browser
  var browser = 'Chrome';
  // We create an error to see how it is handled
  var errFirefox;
  try
  {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-throw-literal
    throw 'a';
  }
  catch (err)
  {
    try
    {
      console.log('before err.toSource() line'); // This line will work on every browser
      err.toSource();
      console.log('after err.toSource() line'); // This line will work only on Firefox browser
      errFirefox = true; // This line will work only Firefox browser
    }
    catch (errOfErr)
    {
      // if err.toSource() throws an exception browser is not a firefox.
      errFirefox = false;
    }
  }
  if (errFirefox && browser !== 'Firefox' && browser !== 'Other')
  {
    console.log("You lied about your browser.");
  } 
  else
  {
    console.log("All fine");
  }
}
hasLiedAboutBrowser();
```

This code tells us when user lied about the browser.

What I need is "change firefox javascript error handling rules" so firefox will handle errors like the other browsers

How can i do this?

1-) Compile firefox from source? (probably if so where is the rules?)

2-) Change some javascript code on omni.ja archive files? (not likely)

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox has `toSource` defined on `String` so just make it undefined:

```
String.prototype.toSource = undefined;
```

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('click', hasLiedAboutBrowser);
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[1].addEventListener('click', function() {
  String.prototype.toSource = undefined;
  console.log('removed toSource from string prototype');
});

function hasLiedAboutBrowser() {
  // Assume browser is Firefox but user agent fakes Google Chrome browser
  var browser = 'Chrome';
  // We create an error to see how it is handled
  var errFirefox;
  try {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-throw-literal
    throw 'a';
  } catch (err) {
    try {
      console.log('before err.toSource() line'); // This line will work on every browser
      err.toSource();
      console.log('after err.toSource() line'); // This line will work only on Firefox browser
      errFirefox = true; // This line will work only Firefox browser
    } catch (errOfErr) {
      // if err.toSource() throws an exception browser is not a firefox.
      errFirefox = false;
    }
  }
  if (errFirefox && browser !== 'Firefox' && browser !== 'Other') {
    console.log("You lied about your browser.");
  } else {
    console.log("All fine");
  }
}
```

```html
<button>Check Browser</button>
<button>remove toSource</button>
```